# Visual studio modules window shows .aspx files instead of DLL name

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, debugging

I am working on an ASP.NET project and getting the dreaded `The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No code has been loaded for this code location`.

I am running in debug configuration, and other projects in the same solution can be debugged properly.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Community edition, in the modules window I see an empty list, I have to right click and select `Show Modules for all Processes` to get anything to appear, and when it appears it does not show the name of the .dll, it shows the name of the .aspx page that the launched browser is currently sitting on, which will update as I navigate around the site.

[image]

From all the answers I have found online, it should be showing the name of my project's .dll file, such as `MyProject.dll`, then you can manually load the symbols from there by looking in the bin directory for `MyProject.pdb` (which does exist), but I am seeing the page name, `Register.aspx`, which of course will not work if I try to load the symbols for `MyProject.pdb`.

Or maybe I'm totally off-base here, I'm happy to provide any info that might help!

Comment: Have you tried doing a clean/rebuild?

Comment: @RonBeyer Yes, I've done a clean/rebuild including manually deleting the build output directory after and have closed/restarted VS and have the same issue.

Comment: Is this happening for local or remote debugging?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning local.  Just running the site from VS by pressing F5 or run.

Comment: @Brendan Can you check the build configuration menu and make sure project is checked?

Comment: @Brendan, Firstly, if just the specific project has this issue, I suggest you create a blank solution, and then copy all your project files to this new solution, clean and rebuild your project/solution, debug it again. In addition, it seems that you use certain version control tool in your side, if possible, just copy your project to a clean path without any version control tool, view the result. Of course, you could also reset your VS settings, and enable the Microsoft symbol servers under TOOLS->Options->Debugging->Symbol. View the result again.

Comment: @Brendan,Would you please share us the latest information about this issue?

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT I'm no longer working on this client's project and no longer have the code that was causing the issue so unfortunately I can't provide an update for you.

Comment: @Brendan, If so, maybe you could delete this case, so other community members don't need to provide the possible solution for this issue. Of course, if you have any issue, you could re-open a new one. Have a nice day:)